# Displaying value after current maximum column value in a textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to display the next to the last row of a table.

edit: forgot that ctr_no is not an int

```
select ctr_no from request_table where req_no = (select max(req_no) from request_table);
```

[image: Sample data and table structure]

Comment: you mean second last column ?

Comment: Next to Last row makes no sense

Comment: uhmm after the last column,

Comment: @NoDisplayName  even if the column is auto incremented?

Comment: Probably should change "next to last row" to "value after current maximum column value" or similar in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery like this (untested; requires 2012 or later):

```
select top 1 'ctr_' + convert(try_parse(substring(ctr_no,3,4) as int) as nvarchar(7)) from request_table where req_no = (select max(req_no) from request_table);
```

Comment: the output was 'ctr0002', i'll try to modify your query hoping to get the answer. Thanks

Comment: On the upside, my code did exactly what I thought it would; on the downside, that wasn't actually what you were asking for. Hopefully fixed.